# How does browser (Chrome) obtain media file duration without downloading full file with video/audio tag?

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, browser, web-audio-api

How does browser (Chrome) obtain media file duration without downloading full file with video/audio tag ?

For example when using audio tag with src set to remote mp3 file (http link)

Is it getting calculated from the first chunk's *Content-Range* HTTP-header field ?

--*P.S. related question: [Is it possible to know the duration of an MP3 before the entire file is downloaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706093/is-it-possoble-to-know-the-duration-of-an-mp3-before-the-entire-file-is-download)*

Comment: Its probably stored in the MP3's file header.

Comment: found answer in https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#AudioBuffer-attributes, another question where does it take sample_rate then

Comment: partially answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49815245/2154075

Comment: Uh, the webaudio AudioBuffer attributes have nothing to do with this question.  For this case, you would have had to download the entire file and decode it to get an AudioBuffer.